# logistic regression always predict the same value when the nework are deeper

Tags: logistic-regression, darknet

im using darknet to train a logistic regresion model. but it always output the same  prediction for different input image.

but when i remove some convolutional layers , it seems to become normal.(different output for different input images)

the model cfg file is as follows:

> [net]
>   some parameter...
>   [convolutions]
>   [convolutions]
>   [shortcut]
>   ...
>   [avgpool]
>   [connected]
>   batch_normalize=1
>   output=1
>   activation=linear
>   
>   [logistic]

i tryed different learning rate, momentum. not work.
and the trainging data is ballanced. two class, 15000images for each class. 
any advices?
thanks.

Comment: and the convolution layer activation function is leaky

Comment: the removed layer is one conv layer thau use stride =2 to do downsample. but the front layer also use this method to do downsample. it is the fourth downsample layer.  could this be the problem?